# Rendering Mesh from TextureRegion renders whole TextureAtlas

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I have a simple render method that I want to use to draw a simple mesh. The code below, using the TextureRegion class instead of Texture renders a dirty and broken mesh. Its seems that the whole Texture Atlas from which the region is extracted is rendered instead of the texture region:

```
public void (SpriteBatch batch, OrthographicCamera camera){
            mesh.setVertices(vert);
            mesh.setIndices(indi);
            Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            shader.begin();
            shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", camera.combined);
            shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);       
            textureRegion_laser.getTexture().bind(0);    
            mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
            shader.end();       
            Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);  
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

The code below which uses a Texture instead of of a TextureRegion draws the mesh correctly. What's the pb?

```
public void (SpriteBatch batch, OrthographicCamera camera){
            mesh.setVertices(vert);
            mesh.setIndices(indi);
            Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            shader.begin();
            shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", camera.combined);
            shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);       
            texture.bind(0);            
            mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
            shader.end();       
            Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);  
            Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. E.g. the `vert` variable should be different depending on the `TextureRegion` but you didn't include it all.

Comment: My question doesn't relate to `vert`.

Comment: Then remove the redundant TextureRegion.

Comment: If you want to use a texture region, you must either modify the uvs of the mesh vertices accordingly, or write a vertex shader that can do that for you, given the texture region parameters as inputs.

Comment: I'm having this same problem and can't seem to figure out how the u/v values should be updated.